I cannot enable Rider version control integration with Perforce
enter image description hereI have the Visual Studio 20222 keymap. As it is now it only gives me the option to use local history for version control integration.
I used P4v to set up a new depot and everything is synced up with my Unreal project, but in the Rider IDE everything seems to be grayed out.enter image description here

key maps shouldn't do that...

I didn't think so but i thought i would mention it. In the picture at the bottom the source control integration box is grayed out and when I click the question mark nothing happens

You need to enable Peforce integration. Here is the instruction. Hope that helps: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Enabling_and_Configuring_Perforce_Integration.html
Have a nice day!
